# Status bar icons disappear and then slowly reappear

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistatusbar

I have found that the status bar will disappear when swapping the window's root view controller.

1. I have `View controller-based status bar appearance` set to NO
2. I am swapping between two different view controllers via 
   `[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window.rootViewController = rootVC;`

Immediately upon displaying the new rootVC the status bar icons all disappear and slowly (10 seconds) begin to reappear.  During this time the UI is responsive otherwise.  I am not otherwise setting the visibility of the status bar via any method that I know to set the status bar visibility.  Neither the old or the new rootVC are displayed as a modal.

Answer (score 1):

So I found that if I changed the `View controller-based status bar appearance` plist property to `YES` and called `[self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate]` from the new rootVC the statusbar icons didn't change.